# Unit testing: Assigning a Custom Obj Auto-Number to String Variable?

Tags: unit-test, dml, failing-tests

I have been trying to successfully compile a Test Class for triggers that auto-insert a DML_Log__c upon a specific sObject type being deleted, and an error keeps getting thrown:

> Expression cannot be assigned at line -1 column -1

Here's the unit test code:

```
//Test class for testing DML Logging
@isTest 
public class testDmlLogger {
static testMethod void testDmlLogging() {

Account testAccount = new Account();
testAccount.Name = 'TrylerTest';
insert testAccount;


Opportunity newTestOpp = new Opportunity();

//setting all Required fields
newTestOpp.Name = 'Master Program Test Opp';
newTestOpp.Sales_Owner_Field_Updater__c = 'Tryhard McTrevor';
newTestOpp.AccountId = testAccount.ID;
newTestOpp.Primary_Media_Opportunity__c = 'Incremental Budget';
newTestOpp.CloseDate = date.parse('10/12/2015');
newTestOpp.StageName = 'Prospecting';
newTestOpp.Type = 'New Business';
//insert the Opportunity sObject
insert newTestOpp;

//Creating new Program record
Program__c testProgram = new Program__c();
Program__c.Name = 'Radagast Records';
//insert Program- default record type is Provisioned, only one field required
insert testProgram;

//Create new Media Placement, a child/Detail object of Program and Opportunity
Media_Placement__c testMedPlc = new Media_Placement__c();
Media_Placement__c.Opportunity_Associated__c = newTestOpp.Id;
Media_Placement__c.Program_Placement__c = testProgram.Id;
//and insert!
insert testMedPlc;

//grabbing testMedPlc Id and Name as a string
String testMedPlcId = testMedPlc.Id;
String testMedPlcName = testMedPlc.Name;
System.debug(testMedPlcName);


//...and now we delete the Media Placement
delete testMedPlc;

//This should insert a DML_Log__c storing the sObject 'Name' and sObject Id values

//Time to SOQL Query! DML Logs
DML_Log__c queriedDmlLog = [SELECT Id,Name,SObject_Type__c FROM DML_Log__c WHERE SObject_Id__c = :testMedPlcId LIMIT 1];
System.assertEquals('Media_Placement__c', queriedDmlLog.SObject_Type__c);

//grab the Program record's Name
String testVerProgName = testProgram.Name;

//Time to delete Program record!
delete testProgram; 

//Time to SOQL! New DML Log
DML_Log__c queriedDmlProgLog = [SELECT Id,Name,SObject_Type__c FROM DML_Log__c WHERE Name__c = :testProgName LIMIT 1];
//sObject type was Program__c, so should be written to field as string
System.assertEquals('Program__c', queriedDmlProgLog.SObject_Type__c);

    }
}
```

**Notes:**

Media_Placement__c object is a detail of Opportunity and Program__c objects

The Media_Placement__c sObject name is an 'Auto-Number' data type,   but when the DML_Log__c sObject is inserted in Sandbox upon either a Program__c or Media_Placement__c deletion, this Auto-Number is successfully written to a string field

Is assigning the Auto-Number data type to a string variable causing the compile error?

P.S. When I tried executing in Dev Console, executing returned this Dialog error:

> Only top-level class methods can be declared static

I have successfully tested in the past, so I am not sure what is causing these issues (I am using v 36.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like simple syntax error to me in below lines

```
/Creating new Veritone Program record
  Program__c testProgram = new Program__c();
 Program__c.Name = 'Radagast Records';///// WRONG WRONG
//insert Program- default record type is Provisioned, only one field required
insert testProgram;
```

You have to use Sobject variable for assignment and not sObject directly

```
/Creating new Veritone Program record
Program__c testProgram = new Program__c();
 testProgram .Name = 'Radagast Records';//Check this here ..
//insert Program- default record type is Provisioned, only one field required
 insert testProgram;
```

Correct the assignment syntax everywhere and you should be good .

Comment: Doh, rookie mistake! Good eye, I did fix that and tried compiling again, but it's still throwing a 'Expression cannot be assigned at line -1 column -1'. 
Any idea what that could refer to?

Comment: Also realized that my Media_Placement__c sObject was incorrectly assigned...thanks again!